# Does anyone know the serial communication protocol for infopia's finetest autocoding premium?

Tags: serialport

I obtained a [finetest auto-coding premium glucometer](https://mdkmart.com/?product=finetest-autocoding-premium-blood-glucose-meter) and I would like to use it to transmit measured data over the Internet to a remote destination as a project. To do that I am connecting to its serial port. However, I have not been able to find any information on what commands are used to retrieve data from it. So far, I have determined that the serial port is UART based: using 0 V for logic 0, and -3 V for logic 1. The port simply echoes any input I send to it without providing additional data.

Comment: In absense of documentation, the usual method is to get some software which already knows how to communicate with your device, look at the signals, and work out the protocol which is likely to be very simple.  Is see in passing that [Diabass software](https://www.diabass.com/free/) claims to be able to communicate with your glucometer.

Comment: See also this git repository which might include your device https://github.com/glucometers-tech/glucometer-protocols, and this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4335/reading-data-from-a-glucose-meter

Comment: @jonathanjo I'll check diabass for the glucometer communication. However, I couldn't find anything about the glucometer in the other links. Would give feedback on the results

Comment: If you use Diabass you might well be able to find out the general scheme of the communication, and there's a decent chance it's like one of the ones in the glucometer-protocols.  Even if it isn't they look like they have good tools for looking at the protocols, and would be interested to have whatever results you find.

Comment: I have downloaded both DIABASS 6 and Infopia's Glucodiary application. After using them. the results are that the app first sends 0x53 to the device which replies with 0x53 as well. nothing happens after that. The glucodiary however sends the sequence 0x53, 0x0D, 0x0A and the glucometer simply responds with the same sequence. Either way, no data is being transmitted.

Comment: Well, I think you have to get some ready-made application to communicate with the device before you can get you own things working with it.  Are there settings in the deive for enabling serial communications.  Can you tell if the response is simultaenous or echoed? (simultaenous like when you short TXD and RXD on the computer; echoed would be that 0x53 from glucometer is *after* 0x0a from computer.)